# Texas ranges in list of lists

Tags: haskell, matrix

This is for a school project.

I have to generate a list of lists with ranges.

Example:

```
myLol x y z = 
[[   x  , x-2 , ... ,  x-y+2 ],
 [  x-2 , x-4 , ... ,  x - y ],
 [  ... , ... , ... ,   ...  ],
 [x-z+2 , x-z , ... , x-y-z+4]]
```

My first thought was to make four lists, and put them together at the end, but that does not give me the 3rd row.
I have played around trying to make list comprehensions inside list comprehension, but that did not turn out any good.

I am quite sure generating the 1st, 2nd, and 4th column, and then the rows from these values would work. I am not skilled enough to figure out the code for it though.

Any ideas?

Edit:
I made it making it only work with a 4x4 matrix. Not working dynamically though.

```
myLol x y z = [(row1 x y),(row2 x y),(row3 x y z),(row4 x y z)]

row1 x y =  take x [x,(x-1) .. (x-y+1)] 
row2 x y =  take x [(x-1),(x-2) .. (x-y)]
row4 x y z = take x [(x-z+1),(x-z) .. (x-y-z+2)] 

row3 x y z = [((row1 x y) !! 2),((row2 x y) !! 2) .. ((row4 x y z) !! 2)]
```

Comment: ``myLol x y z = take (z`quot`2) [take (y`quot`2) [ξ, ξ-2..] | ξ<-[x, x-2..]]``?

Comment: Nested list comprehensions should work fine. Try something similar to `[ [ x+y | x <- [1..10] ] | y <- [1..10] ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your are trying to do something like this:

```
myLol x y z = [ [ x-i-j | i <- [0,2 .. y-2] ] | j <- [0,2 .. z-2]]
```